# How can I use the EJS templating engine in nodeJS/express without doing `res.render`?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, templating

I would like to res.send a JSON object containing a HTML snippet generated from one of my EJS templates.

```
res.send({
    status: "xyz",
    timestamp: new Date(),
    htmlContent: "" //=====> HTML snippet from template.ejs here
});
```

Is that possible somehow?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could "render" the ejs content to a variable and add it to the object.

```
var content='';
res.render('template', function(err, html) {
   content = html;
});
res.send({
    status: "xyz",
    timestamp: new Date(),
    htmlContent: content
});
```

If this is all you want to do, then we can shorten the code:

```
res.render('template', function(err, html) {
   res.send({
     status: "xyz",
     timestamp: new Date(),
     htmlContent: html
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't know because I never used a callback with `res.render` before!

Comment: So `res.render` is sync even if it takes a callback?

Comment: No, with a callback, `render` simply passes the parsed content to the callback's parameter; it is up to you to send it. Since you wanted to wrap the content in a JSON object, before sending it, I simply held the parsed content to be sent, later. Though that just gave me an idea to augment my answer... stay tuned...

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer: Yes, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Long Answer: Yes, though you will need to use the ejs template library yourself:

```
var ejs = require('ejs');
var template = ejs.compile('<h1>Template</h1><p><%= data %></p>'), options);
var renderedTemplate = template({data: 'My Data'});
//renderedTemplate would contain '<h1>Template</h1><p>My Data</p>'
```

This will give you what you want. But it is honestly not that much different from just using `res.render`. Yes, express will have to read the view file, but that is mitigated by caching of templates (which it does). It is also better that your templates are outside your request handler code, IMHO.

Comment: I honestly didn't know `res.render` was able to take a callback. :/  my bad